# How to update the data stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a web page in which a user can 'add' a post or 'update' an existing one. In the code below, my 'add' function works totally fine to add a new post. However, my 'update' function is not working at all. It fails to update the existing post in my data base. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong? Thank You!!

```
class ShareModel extends Model{
public function Index(){
       $this->query('SELECT * FROM shares ORDER BY create_date DESC');
       $rows = $this->resultSet();
       return $rows;
}

public function add(){
    // Sanitize POST
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($post['submit']){
        if($post['title'] == '' || $post['body'] == '' || $post['link'] ==''){
            Messages::setMsg('Please Fill In All Fields', 'error');
            return;
        }
        // Insert into MySQL
        $this->query('INSERT INTO shares (title, body, link, user_id) VALUES(:title, :body, :link, :user_id)');
        $this->bind(':title', $post['title']);
        $this->bind(':body', $post['body']);
        $this->bind(':link', $post['link']);
        $this->bind(':user_id', 1);
        $this->execute();
        // Verify
        if($this->lastInsertId()){
            // Redirect
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
    }
    return;
}



   public function update(){

        $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if($post['update']){

        if($post['title'] == '' || $post['body'] == '' || $post['link'] ==''){
            Messages::setMsg('Please Fill In All Fields', 'error');
            return;
        }



        $title = $post['title'];
        $body = $post['body'];
        $link = $post['link'];


        // Update MySQL
        $this->query('UPDATE shares SET (title, body, link, user_id) VALUES(:title, :body, :link, :user_id) ' );
        $this->bind(':title', $post['title']);
        $this->bind(':body', $post['body']);
        $this->bind(':link', $post['link']);
        $this->bind(':user_id', 1);
        $this->execute(); 

            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');

     }
     return;
  } 



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your update syntax is off.  MySQL's update syntax, which is also what most other databases use, is:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ...
```

In other words, each column is assigned an update value directly using equals.  Try this version:

```
$this->query('UPDATE shares SET title = :title, body = :body, link = :link, user_id = :user_id');
```

Edit: Most of the time, you would also have a `WHERE` clause with an update, unless you really intend to update every record of the table.

Comment: Moreover, there is no WHERE/id condition, so it will update all rows. It is not desired behaviour ("update an existing one").

Comment: @Ahmed If this suggestion fixed your problem, then consider marking this answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

**The SQL UPDATE syntax:**

The general syntax is:

```
UPDATE table-name 
SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
```

To limit the number of records to **UPDATE** append a **WHERE** clause:

> Notice the **WHERE** clause in the UPDATE syntax : The WHERE clause specifies which record or records that should be updated. **If you omit the WHERE clause, all records will be updated!**

the full syntax for the MySQL UPDATE statement when updating one table is

```
 UPDATE table-name 
   SET column-name = value, column-name = value, ...
 WHERE condition
```

OR

The syntax for the UPDATE statement when updating one table with data from another table in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
[WHERE conditions];
```

OR

The syntax for the MySQL UPDATE statement when updating multiple tables is:

```
UPDATE table1, table2, ... 
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
AND conditions;
```

> **Note:** Put the echo or var_dump() to the statement and then exit (); the operation over
>   there. After that you will see the query over to the browser and then
>   copy that query and place in the SQL section and execute the query
>   over there. If you fins all the Operations are correct then you remove
>   the exit and echo and then run the code. Hope so this explanation
>   might be clear for your understanding purpose.
>   Otherwise mybe you can print last SQL query string using **echo $this->last_query();exit;**

By QAL
Happy Coding :)